# Clean keyboard on Macbook Pro 2017

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have a MacBook Pro from 2017.

It has the new keyboard with the shorter travel distances, touchbar, etc.

Some keys have been very sticky recently. What tools + methods can I use to clean the keyboard keys so they no longer stick?

On the older MacBook Pros, you could remove the keys and use compressed air to clean. The newer MacBook Pros don't have enough space to pop them off with a finger nail anymore.

Comment: I heard a MacBook (also with butterfly switches) user contacted the support because some keys stopped working and they recommended him using compressed air. As far as I know there is a little bit space so the air can flow unter the key.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205662

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, there is no room to remove the keys now.

I would highly recommend never trying to remove the key cap from any of the new low travel keyboards. The keys are part of the top case assembly, and are expensive for third party repairs. (And similarly close tolerance on Bluetooth keyboards)

Apple have a very well illustrated procedure now using compressed air only to clean. If that doesn’t work, I would contact Apple support directly and ask for options.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205662

[image: MacBook cleaning image - from Apple https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205662]

*MacBook cleaning image - from Apple*